# Removing input value in Flow after using Previous Button

Tags: workflow, visual-workflow

I have a scenario in Visual Flow where the user enters data into 3 input fields and navigates to next. Then, they use the Previous button to navigate  back to the screen with the input fields and the blank out one of the values.  Upon navigating forward again, the original values are still present (the blanked out input still has its prior value). 
Does anyone have a method to have this "blank out" persist when using the Previous and Next button.  I have had multiple issues related to the Previous button and the way data is cached.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be a cache issue with the page -- as in the cache isn't getting refreshed.  Is this done on a Visualforce page?  If so, try `<apex:page cache="false">`

Comment: Based on my testing the page cache attribute doesn't seem to affect the flow:interview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are they navigating forward after changing the value? If they are using the Forward button on the browser rather than the Next button in the Flow, that could be the problem. Also, does the problem happen when they enter a new value or only when they "blank out" fields?

Comment: They use the Next button to move forward and it only happens when the blank out the field.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the problem in my Flow.  Are you delivering the Flow via Visualforce or with a Link?  And what browser is being used?  I have a public Flow running at http://flow.snugsfbay.com/ and would be interested to know if your user can reproduce the problem in that Flow (which would tell us if it is a problem particular to your user or to your flow).

Comment: Interesting.  We are running it from inside of a VF page. I was NOT able to reproduce in your sample. What are the input types for your fields? Are they private? Ours are Input/Output.

Comment: Where are you setting it as Input/output?  I am pretty sure that is only available for variables and not for input fields.  For example, if I use the Explorer tab, I can check out variables and see that they are either private, input and/or output.  But when I click on screen input fields, they don't have any such characteristic.  So this makes me wonder if your input field has a default value assigned or is the value being assigned to/from a variable?

Comment: Yes, it is being assigned to a variable that eventually gets passed to a subflow.

Comment: Double check all of the assignment process points.  Sounds like the variable is getting assigned but not getting reassigned as soon as they want it to be when they back up and change the value.  By the way, my Flow uses a subflow for the main form you tried as well.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using a decision nodes to direct traffic so that they are always hitting "Next" instead of "Previous" (i.e. the decision node will direct them back to the input screen when they hit next based on some criteria and pass them through to the next on others, like for example one of the fields is blank).

I know "Next" functions as a sort of mini-save state for the Flow so that might fix you problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't really an answer, but you could always disable the ability to use the Previous button in your Flow. It would at least solve the immediate problem, and if the users' work process requires them to navigate back, you can always just present them a copy of the the same Screen element with the previously entered information set as defaults.